# This in that out animation in android

Tags: android, animation

I have a set of 3 images. One image will always be visible to the user. The second image will be behind the first, and will then be "thrown" off the screen with the rotate animation.

The third image will move in, using rotate animation, and will take place of the second image.

I have been able to do this with code, by using AnimationListener for the throwing off of the second image, and then beginning the moving in animation. I am looking for a way to do this with XML. So far I have only found animation-list which is basically a "GIF" maker kind of solution.

Here's an example of what I am trying to do: https://youtu.be/zG8uXjsiDGg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use VectorDrawable

```
Animatable animatable = (Animatable) imageView.getDrawable();
animatable.start();


<animated-vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                 android:drawable="@drawable/vector_pendulum_point">
    <target android:name="left_point" android:animation="@animator/left_point_rotation"/>
    <target android:name="right_point" android:animation="@animator/right_point_rotation"/>
</animated-vector>
```

> right_point_rotation.xml

```
<objectAnimator
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="500"
    android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/fast_out_slow_in"
    android:propertyName="rotation"
    android:repeatCount="infinite"
    android:repeatMode="reverse"
    android:startOffset="500"
    android:valueFrom="1"
    android:valueTo="-35"/>
```

> left_point_rotation.xml

```
<objectAnimator
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="500"
    android:propertyName="rotation"
    android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/fast_out_slow_in"
    android:repeatCount="infinite"
    android:repeatMode="reverse"
    android:valueFrom="-1"
    android:valueTo="35"/>
```

note **android:startOffset**

Reference：https://github.com/ghuiii/AnimationWithoutCode

Comment: Still having trouble to wrap my head around using this. I have added an example. Would love some hints on how to use this method for achieving that effect.

Comment: you can draw svg, [png change to svg](https://convertio.co/zh/png-svg/), or other tools

Answer (score 0):

I did that by using droidsonroids

```
//code
try {
            GifDrawable gif1 = new GifDrawable(getActivity().getAssets(), "Animation6.gif");
            gif1.setLoopCount(0);
            iv_gif.setImageDrawable(gif1);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


//xml
<pl.droidsonroids.gif.GifImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_gif"
            android:layout_width="64dp"
            android:layout_height="64dp"
            tools:adjustViewBounds="true"
            tools:scaleType="centerCrop"
            tools:src="@drawable/default_logo" />

//gradle add dependencies
compile 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.2.0'
```

Comment: I think you got me wrong. I don't need to add a GIF. I need to move out one image and then bring in another.

Comment: ic. sorry to missunderstand you.

Comment: AnimationList is the better option for this one after another animation .